# Only Able to Save The First Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

A problem I'm facing right now is that when I try to save objects, Core Data appears to only save the first one.

**Code to save objects**

```
- (void)savingResCore {
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
ResultMO *resEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Result" inManagedObjectContext:context];

if(indCheck == 1) {
  resEntity.result1 = pena1;
  resEntity.resuName1 = penaNam1;
}
if(indCheck == 2) {
  resEntity.result2 = pena2;
  resEntity.resuName2 = penaNam2;
}
if(indCheck == 3) {
  resEntity.result3 = pena3;
  resEntity.resuName3 = penaNam3;
}
_seqNameChk = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_seqNameChk intValue] - 1];

if([_seqNameChk isEqual:@(0)]){
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

**Code to fetch objects**

```
- (void)fetchResCore {
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *descriptor = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Result" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
request.entity = descriptor;
NSError *error;
NSArray *contArr = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(contArr == nil){
    NSLog(@"Problems fetching data.");
}
else if(contArr != nil) {
    if(contArr.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No objects saved");
    }
    else {
    NSManagedObject *resu = (NSManagedObject *)[contArr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"1 - %@", resu);
    pena1 = [resu valueForKey:@"result1"];
    penaNam1 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena1);
    pena2 = [resu valueForKey:@"result2"];
    penaNam2 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName2"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena2);
    pena3 = [resu valueForKey:@"result3"];
    penaNam3 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName3"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena3);
    NSLog(@"2 - %@", resu);
    }
}
}
```

For example, I have a button that increments `indCheck` by one each time it is pressed and each time it calls up the `fetchResCore` method. Assume `seqNameChk = 2`. For the first time, the attributes `result1` & `resuName1` gets saved successfully. After the button is pressed consecutively, it no longer saves data. Hence, attributes `result2`, `resuName2`, `result3` & `resuName3` does not contain data when retrieved at the `fetchResCore` method.

**Result printed in the console for `resu`**

```
resuName1 = "(\n    Alan\n)";
resuName2 = nil;
resuName3 = nil;
result1 = "(\n    100\n)";
result2 = nil;
result3 = nil;
```

**Result printed in the console for `contArr`**

```
result1 = \"(\\n    100\\n)\";\n    result2 = nil;\n    result3 = nil;\n
resuName1 = \"(\\n    Alan\\n)\";\n    resuName2 = nil;\n    resuName3 = nil;\n
```

Comment: I would expect that given the code you posted that after `indCheck ` is incremented and `savingResCore ` is called again a second `Result` object is created and `resuName2` and `result2` is set.  So you should expect to have three objects, each with only two properties set.

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, I'm only able to retrieve the first object with the two properties.

Comment: I would assume that they are all in the array `contArr` but you are only looking at the first one:  `NSManagedObject *resu = (NSManagedObject *)[contArr objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: Are you changing `_seqNameChk`? Your code only saves if `_seqNameChk` is equal to `@(0)`

Comment: @pesch I tried removing that line, making it save each time, but it still produces the same result.

Comment: @JonRose My bad, when I try to `NSLog` `contArr` it still displays nil on everything that was stated in the question except for `resuName1` & `result1`.

Comment: If `contArr` has only one element then `savingResCore` was called only once.

Comment: My mistake, I tried to `NSLog contArr.count` and ended up with 3, meaning it was all saved successfully. I took a look at the console again and saw the 3 indexes. @JonRose your previous comment is completely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Rose had pointed out,

> I would assume that they are all in the array `contArr` but you are only looking at the first one: `NSManagedObject *resu = (NSManagedObject *)[contArr objectAtIndex:0];`

I printed out `contArr.count` and it resulted in a 3. I've also printed out the contents of the array by using a `for` loop and again, 3 elements which were populated, was displayed.

To solve the problem, I had to rectify `[contArr objectAtIndex:0]` as it only displayed the first element in the array.

In the `fetchResCore` method

```
for(int i = 0; i < contArr.count; i++){
    NSManagedObject *resu = (NSManagedObject *)[contArr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"1 - %@", resu);
    if(pena1.count == 0 && penaNam1.count == 0){
    pena1 = [resu valueForKey:@"result1"];
    penaNam1 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena1);
    }
    if(pena2.count == 0 && penaNam2.count == 0){
    pena2 = [resu valueForKey:@"result2"];
    penaNam2 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName2"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena2);
    }
    if(pena3.count == 0 && penaNam3.count == 0){
    pena3 = [resu valueForKey:@"result3"];
    penaNam3 = [resu valueForKey:@"resuName3"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pena3);
    }
}
```

Thanks again, Jon Rose for pointing out a simple mistake that took me days to figure out.